# Lambda property value selector used in lambda expression

Tags: vb.net, linq

I sometimes find myself writing two versions of the same function that gets a count of members where one of several properties have a particular value.  I've been looking at func and other examples to see if I could write a single function to do a count where a value matches one of several properties of an object.  Feels like there should be a way...

```
Module Test
    Private _students As New List(Of Student)
    Sub Main()
        _students.Add(New Student(1, "Stephen"))
        _students.Add(New Student(2, "Jenny"))

        ' I'd like to replace the following lines...

        Console.WriteLine(GetCountByID(1))
        Console.WriteLine(GetCountByName("Stephen"))

        ' with a single function that could be used like below.

        'Console.WriteLine(GetCountByType(1, Student.ID))
        'Console.WriteLine(GetCountByType("Stephen", Student.Name))

        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetCountByID(ByVal id As Integer) As Integer
        Return _students.Where(Function(s) s.ID = id).ToList.Count
    End Function
    Public Function GetCountByName(ByVal name As String) As Integer
        Return _students.Where(Function(s) s.Name = name).ToList.Count
    End Function

    ' I know this is wrong below but I'm just writing it like I'm thinking about it in my head

    'Public Function GetCountByType(ByVal value As Object, selectorProperty As Func(Of Student)) As Integer
    ' Return _students.Where(Function(s) s.selectorProperty = value).ToList.Count
    'End Function

    Public Class Student
        Public Property ID As Integer
        Public Property Name As String
        Public Sub New(ByVal id As Integer, ByVal name As String)
            Me.ID = id
            Me.Name = name
        End Sub
    End Class 
End Module
```

Comment: You can return dictionary from single function with different counts in it for different keys.

Comment: You are right, but the goal of this function would be to only return one count against a single property.  I only need to get one count at a time based on either property.  Was just wonder if there was a pattern for writing a single function that could get a count from any property of a particular object in a collection.

Comment: Then you need to pass that property as well. Currently you are passing only value because function already know to check property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are along the right lines but your Func needed to return an object.
However it would be better to make it generic instead, the type needs to be of type IComparable so you can check for equality against the target value.

```
Public Function GetCountBy(Of T As IComparable)(selector As Func(Of Student, T), value As T) As Integer
    Return _students.Where(Function(s) selector(s).CompareTo(value) = 0).Count()
End Function

Console.WriteLine(GetCountBy(Function(s) s.ID, 1))
Console.WriteLine(GetCountBy(Function(s) s.Name, "Stephen"))
```

p.s. your calls to ToList() are unnecessary

But once you have gone this far you might as well just pass in the complete predicate instead of a selector function and a value

```
Public Function CountWhere(predicate As Func(Of Student, Boolean))
    Return _students.Where(predicate).Count()
End Function
Console.WriteLine(CountWhere(Function(s) s.ID = 1))
```

You can generalise this even further so it applies to any collection rather than just students, and make it an extension function if you wish

```
Public Function CountWhere(Of T)(coll As IEnumerable(Of T), predicate As Func(Of T, Boolean))
    Return coll.Where(predicate).Count()
End Function
Console.WriteLine(CountWhere(_students, Function(s) s.ID = 1))
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for.  Thank you for taking the time.